# .find is not a function in sails js mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, sails-mongo

I have
ArticlesController.js

```
const Articles = require('../models/Articles');

module.exports = {
  list: async(req, res) => {
    const articles = await Articles.find({});
    console.log(articles);
    res.status(200).json({
      message: 'Articles'
    });
  }
};
```

models/Articles.js

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    title: {
      type: 'String'
    },
    body: {
      type: 'String'
    }
  },
  datastore: 'mongodb'
};
```

config/datastores.js

```
module.exports.datastores = {
  mongodb: {
    adapter: 'sails-mongo',
    url: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/sails-crud'
  },
};
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@sailshq/connect-redis": "^3.2.1",
    "@sailshq/lodash": "^3.10.3",
    "@sailshq/socket.io-redis": "^5.2.0",
    "grunt": "1.0.4",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.25",
    "sails": "^1.4.2",
    "sails-hook-grunt": "^4.0.0",
    "sails-hook-orm": "^3.0.2",
    "sails-hook-sockets": "^2.0.0",
    "sails-mongo": "^1.2.0"
  }
```

But this is the error I get

> error: Sending 500 ("Server Error") response:   TypeError:
> Articles.find is not a function

I have tried using find.exec as well, same error with that as well.
Help me resolve it.

Comment: have you created the collection?

Comment: no, not manually, do I have to create it from the Command line separately, can't I do something like creating it using the api and write the Articles.create() in controllers?

Comment: You can use the api but before you call 'find' the collection has to exist. something like that: MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("mydb");
  dbo.createCollection("Articles", function(err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Collection created!");
    db.close();
  });
});

Comment: ok understood, thanks

Comment: I created the collection using a blueprint and it added data to my local mogodb compass, but still this find throws the same error

Comment: this is probably because your Articles import is basically just an object. you have to connect to your db again and call find like so: MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("sails-crud");
    dbo.collection("Articles").find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(result);
      db.close();
    });
  });

Comment: but this is the traditional mongo way. I might be missing the sails part